# Parsley validation for Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: parsley.js

I have a Bootstrap datepicker:

[image]

This is the HTML code generated when the datepicker is initialized:

[image]

So it's a table there is no input.

What I need is to add a `Parsley` error below the datepicker DIV manually.

I have seen that it's possible to to this for a input element, but don't know how to that to a DIV.

```
 var FieldInstance = $('[name=FieldName]').parsley(),
        errorName = 'This is a test error';

    // now display the error
    window.ParsleyUI.addError(FieldInstance, errorName, response.message);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an input of type "date", probably if hidden. Parsley should be able to validate that.

Pro tip: Always provide a working example.